# Is it possible to nest JUnit 5 parameterized tests?

Tags: java, nested, parameter-passing, junit5

I am attempting to write a parameterized test for an interface Foo, which declares a method getFooEventInt(int, int). I have written a paramterized test that works for a single instance of Foo (a FooImpl object).

```java
public class FooTest {

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("getFooEvenIntProvider")
    public void getFooEvenIntTest(int seed, int expectedResult) {
        Foo foo = new FooImpl();

        Assertions.assertEquals(expectedResult, foo.getFooEvenInt(seed));
    }

    private static Stream getFooEvenIntProvider() {
        return Stream.of(
            Arguments.of(-2,  0),
            Arguments.of(-1,  0),
            Arguments.of( 0,  2),
            Arguments.of( 1,  2),
        );
    }
}
```

However, I'd like to be able to have getFooEvenIntTest(int, int) be invoked against a provided list of Foo implementation instances, with each iteration then using the provide list of seed/expectedResult values.

I realize I could do this as...

```java
public class FooTest {

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("getFooProvider")
    public void getFooImplEvenIntTest(Foo foo) {
        int[] expectedResult = {  0,  0, 2, 2 };
        int[] seed           = { -2, -1, 0, 1 };

        for(int i=0; i<seed.length; i++) {
            Assertions.assertEquals(expectedResult[i],
                                    foo.getFooEvenInt(seed[i]));
        }
     }

    private static Stream getFooProvider() {
        return Stream.of(
                Arguments.of(new FooImpl()),
                Arguments.of(new FooImpl2())
        );
    }
}
```

Any ideas? I'll post if I figure it out, but I thought I'd check to see if this is even doable, or if there's a different approach.

Comment: Find a related feature request at https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1427 and a possible solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56526807/feed-multiple-parameters-in-junit-5-test-method

Answer (score 4):

I guess you think of combining two arguments streams. You could achieve this by creating the cartesian product of two arguments lists.

I have implemented that on https://github.com/joerg-pfruender/junit-goodies/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/joergpfruender/junitgoodies/ParameterizedTestHelper.java

```
public static Stream<Arguments> cartesian(Stream a, Stream b) {
  List argumentsA = (List) a.collect(Collectors.toList());
  List argumentsB = (List) b.collect(Collectors.toList());

  List<Arguments> result = new ArrayList();
  for (Object o : argumentsA) {
    Object[] objects = asArray(o);
    for (Object o1 : argumentsB) {
      Object[] objects1 = asArray(o1);
      Object[] arguments = ArrayUtils.addAll(objects, objects1);
      result.add(Arguments.of(arguments));
    }
  }
  return result.stream();
}

private static Object[] asArray(Object o) {
  Object[] objects;
  if (o instanceof Arguments) {
    objects = ((Arguments) o).get();
  } else {
    objects = new Object[]{o};
  }
  return objects;
}
```

Then your test code will be:

```
  public static Stream<Arguments> fooIntsAndFooProvider() {
    return ParameterizedTestHelper.cartesian(getFooEvenIntProvider(), getFooProvider());
  }

  @ParameterizedTest
  @MethodSource("fooIntsAndFooProvider")
  public void getFooImplEvenIntTest(Integer seed, Integer expectedResult, Foo foo) {
        Assertions.assertEquals(expectedResult,
                                foo.getFooEvenInt(seed));
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

BLUF: I will interpret the crickets to mean "even if you could, you shouldn't be nesting parameterized tests", in which case I run with the approach outlined below.

For an interface *Foo*...

```
public interface Foo {
    public char getFirstChar(String strValue);
    public int  getNextEvenInt(int seed);
}
```

The "best" use of parameterized tests for implementations of *Foo* would be...

```
public class FooTest {

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("getFooProvider")
    public void getFirstCharTest(Foo foo) {
        char[]   expectedResult = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };
        String[] seed           = { "alpha", "bravo", "charlie", "delta" };

        for(int i=0; i<seed.length; i++) {
            Assertions.assertEquals(expectedResult[i],
                                    foo.getFirstChar(seed[i]));
        }
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("getFooProvider")
    public void getNextEvenIntTest(Foo foo) {
        int[] expectedResult = {  0,  0, 2, 2 };
        int[] seed           = { -2, -1, 0, 1 };

        for(int i=0; i<seed.length; i++) {
            Assertions.assertEquals(expectedResult[i],
                                    foo.getFooEvenInt(seed[i]));
        }
    }

    private static Stream getFooProvider() {
        return Stream.of(
                Arguments.of(new FooImplOne()),
                Arguments.of(new FooImplTwo())
                // extend as need for implementations of Foo
        );
    }
}
```

While I won't get the "warm fuzzies" of seeing the passing results for each value-pair in the various tests, it will fulfill my goal of having a test at the interface level that I can easily extend to validate/verify the interface's implementations.